# Remove Enterprise Enrollment from Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome-os

How to remove Enterprise Enrollment from a Samsung chromebook xe303C12 ?
Any help would be appreciated...

I have tried wiping the Chrome OS. I have also tried installing image recovery.
Nothing I've tried has worked.

Comment: did you just reset with esc refresh power or powerwash

Comment: The answer to this depends on whether the enterprise admin has set the device to force re-enrollment or not. If they did, you need to ask the admin to unenroll the device. If not, you can flip it to/from dev mode and that will be enough.

Answer (score 6):

I have had the same problem with my Chromebook. Here's what I did to take it off (**before you start, remove any flash drives or memory devices**):

1. Press <kbd>esc</kbd> + <kbd>refresh</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd> (note: <kbd>refresh</kbd> is the 4th key from the left on the Chromebook. It should be the swirly arrow.)
2. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>space</kbd> (the spacebar) or on some Chromebooks <kbd>enter</kbd> (the enter key) Note: This will put you in developer mode, let your Chromebook load up everything and do NOT turn it off yourself. Your Chromebook will restart and then start initiating dev mode, that will put you off of the domain.

**Important:** If your Chromebook says that dev mode has been blocked by the admin follow these steps:

1. If you see that dev mode is blocked, do NOT turn off your Chromebook, it will take you back to register your Chromebook again do NOT go through this process, instead, try pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> + <kbd>refresh</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd> again.
2. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>space</kbd> (the spacebar) or <kbd>enter</kbd> (enter).
4. Repeat this process continually until it works.

NOTE: Your Chromebook will restart again and hopefully load everything and boot you into dev mode, this means that you will no longer be registered under that school's domain and you can get full functionality out of your Chromebook.

Hopefully, this helps someone.

Comment: This did not work for me--it gives "Developer mode is disabled on this device by system policy." When I try esc+refresh+power again, Ctrl+D does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Do not constantly press the developer mode keys. The repetition of this can crash the BIOS and UEFI information causing your Chromebook to be a mess. I have been in your situation and here's how to do it. Disclaimer: You will have to get your hands a bit dirty and this process may revoke any warranty and static charges may damage the motherboard. Chances of this are low though :D. (These directions are only if you cant activate developer mode because it is blocked)

1. Make sure your Chromebook is off.
2. Unscrew your Chromebook back cover.
3. Unscrew the battery and unplug the power cord connecting the battery and the motherboard.
4. Open your Chromebook and press the <kbd>power</kbd> button for 30 seconds. This should  bypass the admin block.
5. Place the battery back in and connect the power cords. Put the back cover on.
6. Turn your Chromebook on and press <kbd>esc</kbd> + <kbd>refresh</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd> It may take 9-15 minutes to boot based on your device. Do not follow this step until you reach the chrome screen.
7. When you reach the "Chrome Os is missing or damaged" screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>.

It should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to deprovision the device as detailed on Google's Chrome for Work and Education site [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3523633).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

this type a chromebook (samsung xe303c12) to remove enterprise enrollment you have to open the bottom case and look for screw with a  round sticker. remove that sticker and then follow the above instructions. dev mode is write protected by the enterprise domain admin. you must do this in order to enable dev mode. gl.