# Samsung Chromebook 2 Enterprise Lock

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook, google-chrome-devtools

I want to disable the Enterprise Lock that is put on my Samsung Chromebook but for the life of me I unable to. I tried following the instructions here to no avail:

https://superuser.com/a/1142803

I took the back cover off, disconnected the battery, held the power button for 30+ seconds, put everything back together and was able to enable Developer Mode but enterprise lock was STILL there, which means I'm unable to use my own Google account unless it's on the enterprise server.

Does anyone know a solution to this? We were all given Chromebooks as gifts after taking a certification in our school in the UAE but they never mentioned anything regarding Enterprise Locks and such.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is either a misunderstanding and should be clarified with whoever administers or configured these devices, if they were actual gifts to keep *without limitations* all students should be able to have the lock removed without opening the device. If this was provided as a gift but actually is used for surveillance of students outside of school then all students should ideally not accept and instead return the devices.

Regarding the answer you mentioned, this is about a particular mechanism on chrome devices. This is usually a screw that you have to remove to remove write protection which enables you to do [unsafe modifications](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript) to the device. The mechanism may not always be clearly documented or have something obvious printed on it, that's how it was on my N22.

With write protect (hopefully) gone you can do all kinds of things to the firmware, but I don't know if there are any other mechanisms in place to limit tampering on locked and managed devices.

Comment: I honestly don't know who I am supposed to contact regarding this, but either way which screw are you talking about exactly? Someone posted something similar and I started looking for a certain screw it with a sticker on it but I couldn't find anything specific. Mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: That's the problem, there is no clear indication which is the right screw.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Samsung support and they will help you. I did this just earlier and they are processing an RMA for me on 17 Chromebooks with the same problem. No cost to me. I can't say what they will do for you but if your school cannot assist you they along with Google are who you need to contact to resolve this issue. It is an issue with your device not being deprovisoned it sounds like. With that said I am still trying to find a home brew method of fixing the same issue as yours just so I know and can have it as a tool in case this ever happens in the future on anymore I come across not to mention so I can lend a hand and help others.

Below is where to contact. This is from Samsung's online customer support. No need to contact them using that method. Just use the information below.

"We have a dedicated support team who handle this Chromebooks. You can reach them by calling: 1-866-SAM4BIZ (1-866-726-4249) from Mon to Fri between 9AM to 9PM (EST)."

Also here are some links to help you and any others with this problem that would like to know how the process all works.

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6352858

https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/6350022?visit_id=0-636495353441114568-215234000&ctx=ownership&p=ownership&rd=1

(mostly for admins) - https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3523633

Answer (score 0):

You haveta reflash an 8 pin eprom chip on the board with a USB programmer and downloaded software. But it can be done.  ch341a programmer look it up on youtube.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).